# Grails - custom Flash.message rendering

Tags: grails, error-handling, grails-orm, grails-controller, flash-message

I am running a query to check if an entity id exists for multiple account ids. If the result set is not null, then I need to either throw an error or display a flash message.

The code for the method is as below:

```
def save() {

    def SAMLInfoInstance = new SAMLInfo(params)

    def account = Account.get(params?.accountId)        
    SAMLInfoInstance.setAccount(account)

    def samlInfoInstanceList = SAMLInfo.executeQuery("from SAMLInfo " +
        " where account.id <> ? " +
           " and entityId =  ?", [SAMLInfoInstance.accountId, SAMLInfoInstance.entityId])

    if (samlInfoInstanceList?.size > 0){
        flash.message = message(code: 'test.not.created.message', args: [message(code: 'SAMLInfo.label', default: 'SAMLInfo'), SAMLInfoInstance.entityId])
        /*flash.message = "default.not.created.message"
        flash.args = ["SAMLInfo", SAMLInfoInstance.entityId]
        flash.default = "SAMLInfo cannot be created"
        */
        render(view: "create", model: [SAMLInfoInstance: SAMLInfoInstance])
        return
        }

    if (!SAMLInfoInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [SAMLInfoInstance: SAMLInfoInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'SAMLInfo.label', default: 'SAMLInfo'), SAMLInfoInstance.entityId])
    redirect(action: "list", id: SAMLInfoInstance.account.id)
}
```

In my view I render the flash message and the errors in the following manner:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <br/>
        <div class="message" role="status">
        <g:message code="${flash.message}" args="${flash.args}" default="${flash.default}"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        </g:if>
        <br/>

        <g:renderErrors bean="${SAMLInfoInstance}" as="list" />
```

In my message.properties file, I have the following line:

```
test.not.created.message=The SP url {1} is not allowed for this account. Please enter a different value.
```

When I run this code, the flash message displays as the string I pass as message i.e. "test.not.created.message". Also, this string is passed on to display whenever I navigate to any other page which displays flash.message.
I am new to grails and groovy and would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems then:

1 - the message is not being retrieved from your message.properties:

You must have other message.properties files in your project. Give it a check. Because if it's not found, grails shows the code itself instead of the message, since it did not find one. Maybe it's looking for your message in some other properties file, like the one specific for your Locale (ex: pt_BR or en_US). Other than that, you're doing it right using the message(code:...) construct.

2 - Your flash message doesn't disappear:

Instead of flash.message, use request.message.

Comment: That works :)

I went ahead and solved my problem using the following code:
`Obj.errors.rejectValue('entityId', 'Obj.entityId.clash.not.created.message', [message(code: 'Obj.label', default: 'Obj url'), Obj.entityId] as Object [], 'This Obj url is not allowed for this account. Please enter a different value.')`

which uses the method signature that can be found at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue

Comment: What do you mean? The request for flash change?

Answer (score 0):

I think the example you want to follow is [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html).

You only need to resolve the message once ie in the controller or in the view.

So in the controller:

```
flash.message = "test.not.created.message"
flash.args = ["SAMLInfo"]
flash.default = "<default text>"
```

And in the view:

```
<g:message code="${flash.message}" args="${flash.args}"
           default="${flash.default}"/>
```

The [flash scope is cleared at the end of the next request](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) which may explain why you still see the message on the next page.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to assign `flash` and do a `redirect` - then the message will be displayed only once.

Comment: I tried doing a `redirect` but i get an error saying that there has already been a `redirect` prior to this and hence, it cannot be executed. That's why I had to resort to rendering the view.

Comment: @Tiago Farias There are no other messages.properties files in my project and i have not implemented locale specific messages yet, so those 2 possibilities are eliminated.